# wrap first post in different div with array_chunk

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

Im adding every 2 posts in a div, but i also want to get the first post in a different div like this:

```
<div class="first">
  <h2>Post title</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Post title</h2>
  <h2>Post title</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Post title</h2>
  <h2>Post title</h2>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$count     = 5;
$args = array(
    'cat'            => $mag_cat,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'posts_per_page' => $count
);

$posts = get_posts( $args ); ?> 
<?php foreach ( array_chunk ( $posts, 2, true ) as $posts) : 

if ( $posts == 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="first">';
} else {
    echo '<div>';
} 
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

The class .first does not seem to print, what I'm a doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just stop using chunk and just do a normal loop with conditions?

Answer (score 0):

[`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) does not allow you to make the first chunk smaller than the rest. Besides this, it is unclear to me why you would compare the *value* (an array) against an integer.

An inefficient way of accomplishing what you want is by using array_merge and array_slice:

```
foreach(array_merge([[$posts[0]]], array_chunk(array_slice($posts, 1), 2)) as $key => $value) {
  if( $key === 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="first">';
  } else {
    echo '<div>';
  }
}
```

You would probably be better off doing this though, with the appropriate boiler plate around it:

```
if(have_posts()) {
  the_post();

  get_template_part('parts/post', 'first');

  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part('parts/post');
    if(have_posts()) {
      the_post();
      get_template_part('parts/post');
    }
  }
}
```

or even

```
if(have_posts()) {
  the_post();

  get_template_part('parts/post', 'first');

  while(have_posts()) {
    for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++ ) {
      if(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('parts/post');
      }
    }
  }
}
```